# How can I parse json to a C# object (Class)?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON data that I need to parse from C# object.

this is JSON Example.

```
{
    "types":
    [
        [
            "tour_type",
            [
                ["groups",1],
                ["individual",2]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here are my C# classes that are meant to contain that data:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonDeserializationTest
{
    [JsonProperty("types")]
    public class Types
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public List<Type> Values {get;set;}
    }

    public class Type
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public string Key {get;set;}
        [JsonProperty]
        public List<Dictionary<string, int>> Values { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It's not working now.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you sure that is your JSON and you haven't made any mistakes while copying it ? For some reasons I have a feeling that  `"tour_type",` is  `"tour_type":`

Comment: @AnuViswan, "tour_type", is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **JsonSerializer** (System.Text.Json) object.

Code:

```
YourClass obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<YourClass>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also use this code. but error.

Answer (score 1):

Your json has a list of list of the object... but you are declaring only List of the object.

```
public class Types
{
    [JsonProperty("types")]
    public List<List<object>> Values { get; set; } 
        // ------  UPDATE: This can only be list of list of 'object' ------- \\
}
```

Also, you are using the JsonProperty on the class, which is not where that normally goes. You want to use that on the property of the class.

**UPDATE:**

You cannot use `List<List<Type>>` for the json you are getting, it can only be `List<List<object>>`. You have to use object because it can either be a string or a `List<List<string>>`. After you update your `Types` class, you can successfully deserialize the json above.

```
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Types>(json);
```

and based on your json definition, you can access tour_type by using the following code

```
types.Values.First()[0].ToString()
// output: tour_type

List<List<string>> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<string>>>(types.Values.First()[1].ToString())

// data[0]
    [0]: "groups"
    [1]: "1"
// data[1]
    [0]: "individual"
    [1]: "2"
```

Since both of the items in the types are objects, you will either have to convert them to string or a list of list of strings or whatever object they actually are.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But, It's not working.  "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 
'Error converting value "tour_type" to type 'JsonDeserializationTest.Type'. Path 'types[0][0]', line 1, position 25.'"

Comment: @Jawad I know. But It's not my json string. Third party API Response it and can not change this response string.

Comment: @SHL, does this answer your question

Answer (score 1):

The JSON payload in the provided example is formatted quite strangely, especially since it contains seemingly unnecessary array nesting. A payload like this usually includes more nested objects (rather than a bunch of nested arrays). Additionally, it has a list of `(string, int)` pairs, which is semantically very similar to a `Dictionary<string, int>`, but the payload doesn't lend itself to that. **It would be helpful to know where it is coming from (what context) to understand how it might change.**

The example JSON brings up a few questions (that you may want to ask yourself):

- Can the "types" array contain multiple entries (at its immediate nesting)?
- Can the "tour_type" key name appear after the array of `string, int` pairs? Is it possible for an entry where no such name exists?
- What other elements can exist in the arrays within "tour_type"?
- Is it guaranteed that the most nested array will contain just a single `(string, int)` pair?

Similarly, it is hard to understand what the example C# class is trying to encapsulate. Is `List<Dictionary<string, int>>` necessary?

**All that said, here's a solution using the built-in `System.Text.Json` library, that could work for you**. You could write something similar using `Newtonsoft.Json`, if necessary. The solution assumes:

- We can't change the JSON payload (and that the third party API response will always returns something that is structurally similar to the example)
- We can only make minimal changes to the C# class object provided in the example

The solution creates and a `JsonConverter<T>` that uses the low-level `Utf8JsonReader` to manually parse and create the custom object. This is required since nested "[" are being used to delineate what should be objects rather than "{". The converter is then registered by annotating the class with the attribute. Now, simply call `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`, passing in the JSON payload.

```
public class Tours
{
    [JsonPropertyName("types")]
    public List<UserType> Types { get; set; }
}

// Annotate the type to register the converter to use
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomUserTypeConverter))]
public class UserType
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> Values { get; set; }
}

// This will use the low-level reader to build up the UserType
public class CustomUserTypeConverter : JsonConverter<UserType>
{
    // Extra structural validation was done for invalid/incomplete JSON
    // which might be too strict or incorrect and hence might require adjustments.
    public override UserType Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var result = new UserType();

        if (!reader.Read())
        {
            throw new JsonException("Incomplete JSON.");
        }

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
        {
            result.Key = reader.GetString();

            ReadAndValidate(ref reader, JsonTokenType.StartArray);

            int depthSnapshot = reader.CurrentDepth;

            var values = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            do
            {
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    throw new JsonException($"Invalid JSON payload. Expected Start or End Array. TokenType: {reader.TokenType}, Depth: {reader.CurrentDepth}.");
                }

                if (reader.CurrentDepth <= depthSnapshot)
                {
                    break;
                }

                reader.Read();

                if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    string key = reader.GetString();

                    reader.Read();
                    int value = reader.GetInt32();
                    values.Add(key, value);

                    ReadAndValidate(ref reader, JsonTokenType.EndArray);
                }

            } while (true);

            ReadAndValidate(ref reader, JsonTokenType.EndArray);

            result.Values = values;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void ReadAndValidate(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType expectedTokenType)
    {
        bool readNext = reader.Read();
        if (!readNext || reader.TokenType != expectedTokenType)
        {
            string message = readNext ?
                $"Invalid JSON payload. TokenType: {reader.TokenType}, Depth: {reader.CurrentDepth}, Expected: {expectedTokenType}" :
                $"Incomplete JSON. Expected: {expectedTokenType}";
            throw new JsonException(message);
        }
    }

    // Implement this method if you need to Serialize (i.e. write) the object
    // back to JSON
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, UserType value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here's how you would use the above converter to serialize the JSON string provided in the example, along with how to access the values.

```
public static Tours ParseJson(string json)
{
    Tours tours = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Tours>(json);
    return tours;
}

public static void AccessValues(Tours tours)
{
    foreach (UserType data in tours.Types)
    {
        string typeName = data.Key; // "tour_type"

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pairs in data.Values)
        {
            string key = pairs.Key; // "groups" or "individual
            int value = pairs.Value; // 1 or 2
        }
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, Visual Studio suggests the following C# class structure for the example JSON (which is similar to what @Jawad suggested):

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public object[][] types { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out your JSON so I created an example with verified JSON.

Try this:

**JSON**:

```
{
        "Items": [
                {
                        "Name": "tour",
                        "Attributes": [
                                {
                                        "Name": "groups",
                                        "Value": 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "Name": "individual",
                                        "Value": 2
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "Name": "demo",
                        "Attributes": [
                                {
                                        "Name": "this is demo",
                                        "Value": 3
                                },
                                {
                                        "Name": "design pattern",
                                        "Value": 99
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}

Types foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Types>(jsonString);

public class TypeAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    private readonly ICollection<TypeAttribute> _attributes;

    public Type()
    {
        _attributes = new Collection<TypeAttribute>();
    }

    public void AddAttributes(IEnumerable<TypeAttribute> attrs)
    {
        foreach(TypeAttribute ta in attrs)
        {
            _attributes.Add(ta);
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TypeAttribute> Attributes
    {
        get { return _attributes; }

        set 
        { 
            foreach(TypeAttribute ta in value)
            {
                _attributes.Add(ta);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Types
{
    ICollection<Type> _items;

    public Types()
    {
        _items = new Collection<Type>();
    }

    public void AddItems(IEnumerable<Type> tps)
    {
        foreach (Type t in tps)
        {
            _items.Add(t);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }

        set
        {
            foreach (Type t in value)
            {
                _items.Add(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. but, I never change json string. It's not mine. It's Third party API Response. so I can't not change.

Comment: @SHL let me know how it turns out